# Example of a monoid required for union operation

Tags: group-theory, semigroups, monoid

Consider $(G,\cup)$ to be a groupoid defined with respect to the union operation.

Let $G=\{A,B,C\}$ ,   where $C= A \cup B$ and $A$, $B$ are any arbitrary sets.

1. $(G,\cup)$ is closed.
2. Associative law holds for the group.
3. Identity element seems to exists but doesn't as it isn't unique

   $A \cup A=A=A \cup \{ \}$

Is it possible to define a semi group with respect to the operation mentioned above and obtain a monoid or even a group ?

Comment: I don't think you understand what an identity element is. Also, to get a group you would need inverses for each element. How likely is it that you can do that?

Comment: Let e be an identity element, then e·A=A=A·e  since A U A gives A , can we say it is an identity element in the group. Yes, we need an inverse for each element and in case of the union operation it doesn't look possible.

Comment: But since the identity element isn't unique, it fails the test. Doesn't it ?

Comment: $e·A=A=A·e$ needs to be true for all $A$. There is only one possibility for such an $e$.

Comment: @Arnaud Mortier. Yes, it has to be unique in a group.Can you give an example of a similar groupoid G where identity elements exists with regards to union.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several issues in your question. In particular, it is ambiguous to call $G$ a *groupoid*, and later a *group*. To start with, $G$ is only a set, and union is not an operation on $G$, but on the set $P(G)$ of subsets of $G$. Moreover, it is not correct to say that $G$ is closed, for two reasons: first, you are actually not considering $G$ but $P(G)$. Moreover, it is not correct to say that $P(G)$ is closed. The right way would be to say that $P(G)$ is closed under the union operation (or simply under union).

Thus, I hope you will not mind if I first rephrase your question as follows:

> Let $G$ be a set. Consider the set of all subsets of $G$, equipped
>   with the union as operation. I already observed that this operation is
>   associative. What type of algebraic structure does it define: a
>   semigroup, a monoid, a group?

**Answer**. It defines a *commutative monoid*. You already observe that union
is associative and hence defines a structure of semigroup. It is a commutative semigroup since for all subsets $E$ and $F$ of $G$, $E \cup F = F \cup E$.
Furthermore, the empty set is the identity for this operation, since, for every subset $E$ of $G$, $E \cup \emptyset = \emptyset \cup E = E$.

The only case when you obtain a group is when $G$ is the empty set. Do you see why it is a group in this case? If $G$ is nonempty, the full subset $G$ has no inverse. Indeed, an inverse would be a subset $E$ of $G$ such that $G \cup E = \emptyset$, but this would imply $G = \emptyset$, a contradiction.

Comment: I am a little confused with regards to the empty set being the Identity for this operation as E U E also gives us E, where E is a subset. Does it have to be unique in that sense ?

Comment: The definition of an identity for this operation is a subset $E$ such that, for **all** subsets $F$ of $G$, one has $F \cup E = E \cup F = F$. Thus knowing that $E \cup E = E$ is not enough. Try to replace $F$ by $\emptyset$ in $F \cup E = E \cup F = F$ and see what happens.

Comment: Thanks for clearing up the mess.

Comment: You're welcome.